# How to get RVM to set correct gem path

Tags: rvm

On a clean Mac OS X "Snow Leopard" install, I have a problem with RVM: It sets the Ruby path correctly but doesn't set the gem path. When I start a Rails server it mixes versions which doesn't work.

To illustrate:

> **$ rvm system**
>   **$ which ruby**
>   /usr/bin/ruby
>   **$ which rails**
>   /usr/bin/rails
>   **$ rvm use 1.9.2-head**
>   Using /Users/m/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head
>   **$ rvm gem list**
>
> LOCAL GEMS
>   [...]
>   rails (3.0.7)
>   [...]
>
> **$ which ruby**
>   /Users/m/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby
>   **$ which rails**
>   /usr/bin/rails
>
> **$ echo $GEM_PATH**
>   /Users/m/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180:/Users/m/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global
>
> **$ echo $PATH**
>   /Users/m/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/Users/m/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2p180@global/bin:/Users/m/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2p180/bin:/Users/m/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: did you do 'gem install rails' after you did 'rvm use 1.9.2-head' ??

Comment: it looks like you're using a previous rails version which came with OS X -- and which was not installed under RVM

Comment: I am also on fresh install of OS X & rvm & ruby 1.9.2. I am not using gemsets, just typing `rvm 1.9.2`. As far as I remember, I have installed bundler with `gem install` and it has been installed in correct location: `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/`; `which bundle` points to this location. All remaining gems were installed with bundler and they are placed in `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/`. This location is not present in $GEM_PATH nor its bin is present in $PATH. Please check this location, maybe you'll find your gems there. BTW `bundle exec` works for me.

Answer (score 12):

So after 1 1/2 days of torture, reading through at least 50 posts, and installing RVM, Ruby and Rails multiple times, I am finally able to use Rails in my RVM install.

This was the last series of events that I did after installing RVM and Ruby the last time and then it worked:

I removed these from `.gemrc`  so back up your file if you do this:

- `gemhome: /home/[user]/ruby/gems`
- `gempath: []`
- `--remote`

then use

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

then

```
gem install rails
```

It seems the trick was:

1. Change the `.gemrc` file.
2. Do *not* create and use a gemset (`rvm use 1.9.3@rails3`) before installing Rails.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you're always 'using' your Ruby version. (Ugh. RVM can be so annoying).

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

Also what does your `.gemrc` look like? I had to take out `--user` from mine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do a `gem install rails` after setting the default Ruby version:

```
  rvm use 1.9.2-head
  gem install rails
```

and then check again with `which rails`.

Comment: I did that, of course. Still haven't figured this out, but got a new computer in the meantime, so I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: I saw a similar problem when having rvm use the ruby version from a local .rvmrc file ... in this case the paths were not set correctly, and you need to do: rvm use ...