# Cocoapods ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOTSUP)

Tags: rubygems, cocoapods

Trying to install Cocoapods. Using system Ruby on OS X 10.9.4, ruby 2.0.0p451.

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

in my home directory gets this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOTSUP)
    Operation not supported - /home/[my city name]
```

The city name thing is weird, there is no directory called that...

Not experienced with Ruby or gems, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran into more issues running init/install here.

There were values in gem env (GEM_PATH and GEMHOME) that were not real paths. Not sure where they came from. I edited .gemrc to remove these definitions and the --remote flag, per https://stackoverflow.com/a/12059734/1417584 . This solved my issues for installing and using pod.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ gem env
```

showed a weird path for gemhome. I guess I screwed up the path somewhere? (That's why the city name). I did

```
$ sudo gem install --user-install cocoapods
```

to install in my home dir, and it works so far.