# How to get Cocoapods running with RVM?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, cocoapods

Unfortunately, I recently upgraded the system Ruby to 2.3 on my Mac. Since I have to use Cocoapods 0.39 for a [specific project](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4699) which does not properly work, I would like to use an older version of Ruby. For this purpose, I installed RVM and then switched to `ruby-2.2-head`:

```
> \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
> rvm install 2.2-head
> rvm use 2.2-head --default
```

This worked fine. Then I tried to install Cocoapods and got the usual error message:

```
> rvmsudo gem install cocoapods

Warning: can not check `/etc/sudoers` for `secure_path`, falling back to call via `/usr/bin/env`, this breaks rules from `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

    export rvmsudo_secure_path=1

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.

In case there is no `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

    export rvmsudo_secure_path=0
```

which I silenced by chosing the second option. Then I checked Cocoapods and got a fantastic error message:

```
> pod --version

/Users/bastian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:250:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
  from /Users/bastian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:278:in `activate_bin_path'
  from /Users/bastian/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

Furthermore, Cocoapods is not listed with the following command:

```
> gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.6)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.1)
psych (2.0.8)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
```

Cocoapods seems to be installed into the wrong directory:

```
> which pod
/Users/bastian/bin/pod
```

So if I switch back to the system Ruby, the `pod --version` command returns `0.39.0`.

I guess that somehow Cocoapods was not installed with the RVM Ruby but rather with the system version. What did I do wrong?

Comment: This smells like a `sudo`-based problem. On a single-user system using `sudo` can really confuse things quickly because it implies RVM will act upon the system version of Ruby, not the individual user's version in the home directory. https://rvm.io/rvm/install#installing-rvm is the definitive documentation for this.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of "[How to get RVM to set correct gem path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840366/rvm-doesnt-set-correct-gem-path)" I was able to solve the problem. I don't know why but the removal of the single entry `--user` from `.gemrc` solved this problem for me. Since the file only contained this one line I just renamed it and reinstalled Cocoapods:

```
 > mv ~/.gemrc ~/.gemrc_backup
 > gem install cocoapods`
```

Now Cocoapods is working again as it resides at the correct path:

```
> which pod
/Users/bastian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2-head/bin/pod
```

Comment: Was it not related to you install firstly with `rvmsudo gem install` and then re-installing it with `gem install`?

Comment: Just to add to this I did both `mv ~/.gemrc ~/.gemrc_backup` and `mv ~/.gem ~/.gem_backup` and then ran `gem install cocoapods`