# Cocoapods claims to install but does not work

Tags: cocoapods, homebrew

I ran the install of cocoapods by using `sudo gem install cocoapods`.

The command claims to have completed successfully. However when I do `gem list cocoapods` it doesn’t show in list. And when I do `pod --version` I get an error:

```
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:271:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:299:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling. I think the problem has to do with having an older version 1.0.1 that was installed with Homebrew, and then installing over it using gem install. But I’m not sure.

I also tried uninstalling the Homebrew version as well, but no luck.

Comment: Trying to use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914557/how-to-get-cocoapods-running-with-rvm, but cannot find .gemrc.

Comment: I suspect you have installed cocoapods on your system default Ruby since you are using sudo. When using RVM, you should simply use gem install [the gem]

Answer (score 1):

I have followed @oyvindhauge advice and it worked like a charm. Just type:

```
gem install [gem]
```

Good luck!