# When I run pod install, I get the message that gem cocoapods cannot be found. How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

Ever since I integrated rvm into my xcode project, I am not able to install any pods. When I run pod install, I get the message that gem cocoapods cannot be found. How can I resolve this issue?

I have already tried looking at this link ([Cocoapods claims to install but does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46438176/cocoapods-claims-to-install-but-does-not-work)) but to no avail.

Bhaveshs-MacBook-Air:moneymiles bhaveshshah$ pod install
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:241:in `bin_path': can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in`'

Pods should have been installed properly but fail to do so.

Comment: First try to run pod init command to initialise pod file.

Comment: @ShivJaiswal i tried pod init but I got the same message.

Comment: Check *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904588/cocoapods-not-installing* link may be it help you to solve problem.